# Pregunta sobre sockets

Tags: python

Hola tengo una duda sobre sockets voy a intentar explicarme todo lo mejor posible para que podais solventar esta duda que tengo espero no decepcionarles con mi cuestion. Bueno, el problema que tengo es que cuando estoy usando un cliente puedo ponerle tantos sockets como yo quiera simplemente como siempre asi:

```
server1=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server1.connect((servidor,8081))
```

Y puedo incluso usar diferentes sockets con los mismos puertos. Lo cual me resulta curioso. Pero cuando cierro estos sockets de esta manera desde el cliente

```
server1.close()
```

Para volver a utilizarlos no puedo tengo que crear otra vez un segundo socket para hacer otra cosa o repetir la misma cosa que hice antes.

Entonces mi pregunta es hay alguna manera de cerrar los sockets para que pueda reutilizarlos y incluso hacer un bucle para repetir determinadas cosas. Ya que es muy molesto crear un socket a cada vez que quiero hacer algo y ademas estoy muy limitado

Probe con close pero no se cierra.

Answer (score 1):

al parecer tienes bastantes dudas sobre sockets. Primero que nada te recomendaría estudiar a mas profundidad en concepto de socket e hilos.

En general existen dos familias principales y las mas usadas de socket que son **TCP** y **UDP**. Los socket TCP son orientados a la conexión (por cierto los mas usados), los sockets UDP trabajan en modo desconectado.

Cuando usas socket TCP te habras dado cuenta que hay metodos bloqueantes, es decir que detienen la ejecucion del programa mientras esperan su proposito, por ejemplo un server socket el metodo **acept** este detiene la ejecucion del programa hasta que llegue una solicitud de conexion, entonces este crea un socket client, le asigna un puerto y a partir de ahi vuelve a esperar a otra conexión bloqueando nuevamente la ejecución del programa.
Un socket client, se bloquea cuando usas el metodo **recv** hasta que el otro socket del otro extremo envie datos.
Es muy útil usar hilos cuando trabajas con socket, normalmente el server socket debería correr en un hilo y tu programa principal recibir los sockets para su uso, cada socket client deberian de correr también en un hilo en particular cuando uses el método recv.

A lo mejor para la aplicación que estas desarrollando necesitas sockets UDP.

Comment: Tienes razon iba a borrar el post me di cuenta antes gracias por tu explicacion si exactamente necesitas siempre hacer hilos tanto en cliente como servidor para cerrar la conexion y poder utilizarla mas veces